# How to calculate magnitude and direction of rotation between two rotational quaternions

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, quaternions

I have a dataset which contains rotational quaternions. How do I find the magnitude and direction (clockwise/anti-clockwise) of rotation between any two of the quaternions.

```
       X       Y           Z            W
-0.053306   0.006596    0.002506    0.998553
-0.053297   0.006629    0.002509    0.998554
-0.053327   0.006654    0.002514    0.998552
```

Comment: Hint: X X =-x^2 is the vector norm, X Y + Y X is the (negative) scalar product and X Y - Y X is th cross product.

Comment: Could you be more direct? @RolandF. I am new to quaternions.

Comment: a quaternion has form $a + bi +cj + dk$, where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, and $i, j, k$ are special quaternions satisfying $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$, Which of $x, y, z, w$ is the real part (corresponding to $a$ in my example form)?

Comment: x,y,z = b,c,d and w=a for the above example that you provided @PaulSinclair

Comment: Also, quaternions are commonly used to specify rotations of 3-dimensional vectors themselves, not a rotation between pairs of quaternions. And "clockwise/anti-clockwise" rotations is a concept defined for rotations in a plane, not rotations in 3D space, where such directions will depend on which way the observer is facing. Can you be more specific about how these quaternions are being used?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) is a wikipedia article on the usual tie-in between quaternions and rotations of 3-dimensional vectors.

Comment: These quaternions are generated from a motion capture software that tracks the movement of landmark(neck, head) in 3D space. I just wanted to calculate how much these landmarks rotate @PaulSinclair

Comment: You will need to read up on that software to find how exactly these quaternions relate to the physical measurements. It is impossible to answer your questions without knowing this information. If each quaternion represents the rotation between two positions of the head, then effectively the answer to your question is found in the wikipedia article. If it represents something else, then some more math will be needed.

Comment: Also, quaternions represent a rotation around a fixed point unaffected by the rotation. With motion capture, one can expect there is a translation component as well. Are you just ignoring the translation component in your question as you understand that part, or does your data just consist of the quaternions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I look into how these quaternions relate to the physical objects. @PaulSinclair